# Mix "traditional" controllers with Castle-Windsor controllers. Is this possible?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, dependency-injection, castle-windsor

I'm integrating a series of controllers into an existing project which already contain controllers which use Castle Windsor for DI/IoC.  I've modified the Installer to only register Controllers in a certain namespace (specifically the root).  This modification appears to be working.  When I try to access my controllers, which do not use Castle Windsor and are located in a different namespace (specifically, a custom Area), I get the error message:  "No component for supporting the service [Controller Name] was found".

Is it possible to mix "traditional" controllers with controllers which use Castle Windsor in a single project?

Does this make sense?

Comment: what's a "traditional controller" and how does that differ from other controllers?

Comment: "traditional", in this sense, is a controller which does not use DI or IoC.  Very basic controller.

Answer (score 1):

If you are getting that error, you are trying to resolve the controller (directly or indirectly) through the container.

If you have a separate logic path that needs a controller that isn't register from the container, nothing is stopping you from calling `new MyController()`.

As an aside, thinking in terms of the controller *using* the container is somewhat backwards.  The container manages your instances--your instances have no idea whether they are container-managed or not.

Comment: Can I have two sets of controllers in the same project, one which uses Castle Windsor and the one which does not?

Comment: Absolutely.  The container won't interfere with anything that it isn't managing.  Even if the container DOES manage an instance of a controller, there is nothing stopping you from creating it independent of the container.  Again, your error message indicates that the container was involved in the way you were trying to use the controller, so the problem is likely in HOW you are creating the controller, not the fact that it is in the same project/assembly.